# With URI gem in Ruby, how do I actually parse this cookie that has paths, etc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cookies

When I get some cookies back from the server, I'm needing to only pass the key=value parameters in the next request. I don't need the path information, expiration, etc. However, when I inspect the hash, I get all of that back and find no real way to only parse and keep the important information.

For example, here's the cookie returned from my HTTP POST request:

```
[1] pry(main)> headers['Cookie']
=> "ds_user=testuser; expires=Fri, 01-Sep-2017 22:20:55 GMT; Max-Age=7776000; Path=/, rur=ATN; Path=/, csrftoken=V6pcoCJdHJLb7BGu2BV8TwE5ZoA5fm; expires=Sat, 02-Jun-2018 22:20:55 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; Secure, mid=WTM2RwABAAHw09zRkX55hIbjqszz; expires=Fri, 29-May-2037 22:20:55 GMT; Max-Age=630720000; Path=/, uid=554580241; expires=Fri, 01-Sep-2017 22:20:55 GMT; Max-Age=7776000; Path=/, sessionid=4be2b3d03caf0f3073ce8f1215a2d723a23981a52b0c%3AZ0Y0P0yRXSvpy2gBwZguWo4zoOpGajRA%3A%7B%22_auth_user_id%22%3A5545802841%2C%22_auth_user_backend%22%3A%22accounts.backends.CaseInsensitiveModelBackend%22%2C%22_auth_user_hash%22%3A%22%22%2C%22_token_ver%22%3A2%2C%22_token%22%3A%225545802841%3Ai2MlZYtSByn9IVBMuL8AHkCq0fX4HI7N%3A480fd4a05bfcdd081c70d0c4c4391883064a35cdd43402506937e611590d92a2%22%2C%22_platform%22%3A1%2C%22last_refreshed%22%3A1496528455.4560296535%7D; expires=Fri, 01-Sep-2017 22:20:55 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=7776000; Path=/; Secure"
```

I can't do something like `headers['Cookie'].split("; ")` because the semicolon `(;)` appears at random parts of the cookie returned in the header.

So for example, when I submit the next request using the cookies returned from that request, it needs to look something like:

```
Cookie: csrftoken=hgsdco49G6E1EOyR48ofKhtG0P; ds_user=testuser; uid=55458041; mid=WTIRigABAAFjQJOKtJ3jaWGbi70P; rur=ATN; sessionid=a9c568a15f567fb8bf9752a3%3AIMAaCgikVRROWcqGu6aoBhJTx5VGutKh%3A%7B%22_auth_user_id%22%3A5545802841%2C%22_auth_user_backend%22%3A%22accounts.backends.CaseInsensitiveModelBackend%22%2C%22_auth_user_hash%22%3A%22%22%2C%22_token_ver%22%3A2%2C%22_token%22%3A%225545802841%3AyvzFW559ItJDPMOY9CyBja4NfW049qxy%3A4c5e7c48a20d3c8a1cbc4d0f9a0631449ff24c9b1dbc35a0f80f50568d0a3365%22%2C%22_platform%22%3A1%2C%22last_refreshed%22%3A1496453514.4971137047%7D
```

Any idea what the easiest way to achieve this would be?

Answer (score 0):

Considerer that the cookie is separed by ";" and under the Path is separated by commas you can proceed working as follow:

```
pry(main)> cookie = headers['Cookie']
=> "ds_user=testuser; expires=Fri, 01-Sep-2017 22:20:55 GMT; Max-Age=7776000; Path=/, rur=ATN; Path=/, csrftoken=V6pcoCJdHJLb7BGu2BV8TwE5ZoA5fm; expires=Sat, 02-Jun-2018 22:20:55 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; Secure, mid=WTM2RwABAAHw09zRkX55hIbjqszz; expires=Fri, 29-May-2037 22:20:55 GMT; Max-Age=630720000; Path=/, uid=554580241; expires=Fri, 01-Sep-2017 22:20:55 GMT; Max-Age=7776000; Path=/, sessionid=4be2b3d03caf0f3073ce8f1215a2d723a23981a52b0c%3AZ0Y0P0yRXSvpy2gBwZguWo4zoOpGajRA%3A%7B%22_auth_user_id%22%3A5545802841%2C%22_auth_user_backend%22%3A%22accounts.backends.CaseInsensitiveModelBackend%22%2C%22_auth_user_hash%22%3A%22%22%2C%22_token_ver%22%3A2%2C%22_token%22%3A%225545802841%3Ai2MlZYtSByn9IVBMuL8AHkCq0fX4HI7N%3A480fd4a05bfcdd081c70d0c4c4391883064a35cdd43402506937e611590d92a2%22%2C%22_platform%22%3A1%2C%22last_refreshed%22%3A1496528455.4560296535%7D; expires=Fri, 01-Sep-2017 22:20:55 GMT; HttpOnly; Max-Age=7776000; Path=/; Secure"

pry(main)> cookie.split(";").each do |f|
        f =~ /^(.*?)=(.*?)$/
      if $1 == " Path" then
        puts "There is a #{$1} that contains #{$2}"
      else
       puts "#{$1} = #{$2}"
      end
    end

pry(main)* ds_user = testuser
 expires = Fri, 01-Sep-2017 22:20:55 GMT
 Max-Age = 7776000
There is a  Path that contains /, rur=ATN
There is a  Path that contains /, csrftoken=V6pcoCJdHJLb7BGu2BV8TwE5ZoA5fm
 expires = Sat, 02-Jun-2018 22:20:55 GMT
 Max-Age = 31449600
There is a  Path that contains /
 Secure, mid = WTM2RwABAAHw09zRkX55hIbjqszz
 expires = Fri, 29-May-2037 22:20:55 GMT
 Max-Age = 630720000
There is a  Path that contains /, uid=554580241
 expires = Fri, 01-Sep-2017 22:20:55 GMT
 Max-Age = 7776000
There is a  Path that contains /, sessionid=4be2b3d03caf0f3073ce8f1215a2d723a23981a52b0c%3AZ0Y0P0yRXSvpy2gBwZguWo4zoOpGajRA%3A%7B%22_auth_user_id%22%3A5545802841%2C%22_auth_user_backend%22%3A%22accounts.backends.CaseInsensitiveModelBackend%22%2C%22_auth_user_hash%22%3A%22%22%2C%22_token_ver%22%3A2%2C%22_token%22%3A%225545802841%3Ai2MlZYtSByn9IVBMuL8AHkCq0fX4HI7N%3A480fd4a05bfcdd081c70d0c4c4391883064a35cdd43402506937e611590d92a2%22%2C%22_platform%22%3A1%2C%22last_refreshed%22%3A1496528455.4560296535%7D
 expires = Fri, 01-Sep-2017 22:20:55 GMT
 = 
 Max-Age = 7776000
There is a  Path that contains /
 = 

=> ["ds_user=testuser",
 " expires=Fri, 01-Sep-2017 22:20:55 GMT",
 " Max-Age=7776000",
 " Path=/, rur=ATN",
 " Path=/, csrftoken=V6pcoCJdHJLb7BGu2BV8TwE5ZoA5fm",
 " expires=Sat, 02-Jun-2018 22:20:55 GMT",
 " Max-Age=31449600",
 " Path=/",
 " Secure, mid=WTM2RwABAAHw09zRkX55hIbjqszz",
 " expires=Fri, 29-May-2037 22:20:55 GMT",
 " Max-Age=630720000",
 " Path=/, uid=554580241",
 " expires=Fri, 01-Sep-2017 22:20:55 GMT",
 " Max-Age=7776000",
 " Path=/, sessionid=4be2b3d03caf0f3073ce8f1215a2d723a23981a52b0c%3AZ0Y0P0yRXSvpy2gBwZguWo4zoOpGajRA%3A%7B%22_auth_user_id%22%3A5545802841%2C%22_auth_user_backend%22%3A%22accounts.backends.CaseInsensitiveModelBackend%22%2C%22_auth_user_hash%22%3A%22%22%2C%22_token_ver%22%3A2%2C%22_token%22%3A%225545802841%3Ai2MlZYtSByn9IVBMuL8AHkCq0fX4HI7N%3A480fd4a05bfcdd081c70d0c4c4391883064a35cdd43402506937e611590d92a2%22%2C%22_platform%22%3A1%2C%22last_refreshed%22%3A1496528455.4560296535%7D",
 " expires=Fri, 01-Sep-2017 22:20:55 GMT",
 " HttpOnly",
 " Max-Age=7776000",
 " Path=/",
 " Secure"]
```

Be careful with the space after ; and proceed with whath you wnat inside the path